# Will this NMOS MOSFET reverse-polarity protection circuit work?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, protection, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

Based on the helpful advice from the community, I realised [the first schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/675747/n-channel-mosfet-reverse-voltage-protection-proposal) I made would **not** work as a protection for reverse polarity well due to a couple of flaws including the diode having to be reversed and the circuit not working without a load + the risk of creating an oscillator.

**So I updated the schematic, very similar to the one proposed by Tim** in the question linked above, ***BUT***, (as of how I think it's logical), with the NMOS's pins flipped. (**source to GND and Drain to output**).
This is it:
[image]

Let me know if I got the working of this right based on the following description:

**System ratings**: Vin=55V, Vz=35V, For use in a buck converter. NMOS is chosen over PMOS because they have a much lower Rds(on)

**OPTION 1 - CORRECT POLARITY**
[image]
When the polarity is right, the mosfet is pulled to Vin through Rm23, **so it starts conducting a bit and Vgs will for a short moment be <=55V** (Red Arrows). Once it starts conducting and GND hits the zener (Black arrows), the voltage across its leads becomes Vin-Vz=55-35=20V, **which are applied to the gate (purple arrows). Vgs=Vg-Vs (GND=0V)=20V-0=20V**, perfect!

**OPTION 2 - WRONG POLARITY**

[image]

When the polarity is WRONG, the mosfet gate is pulled to GND, and it doesn't conduct anything. Happy ending.

Did I get it? **Is my understanding of this circuit right?** **Tim had the drain and source reversed**, why did he do that? The MOSFET will only turn on if the Vgs is  positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Let me know if I got the working of this right...*

The zener diode is no longer protecting gate and source from excessive over-voltage in your modified circuit. That's a showstopper in most cases. Now you have reversed drain and source, the internal body diode will conduct on the reverse voltage you are trying to prevent.

> *...based on the following description*

Irrespective of the description, the circuit is wrong and won't work hence, a description of a wrong circuit is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. This won't work as reverse polarity protection. Look at the body diode of that mosfet. It will conduct if the polarity is reversed.

Try to swap source and drain.

Comment: If we **reverse** the MOSFET's source and drain, then will it work? And if yes, how does it? In our example of Vin=55V and Vz=35V, **how can we calculate the voltage at the mosfet's gate?** It **must** be positive

Comment: @Mito I think it should.